# How to read jpg using FreeImage

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, freeimage

I am new to FreeImage. I just want to read an JPEG image and display it in my MFC dialog. How do I do that? I try that using ImageStone by doing:

```
 img.Load(blob.data, size, IMG_JPG);
 img.Draw(hdc, DC);
```

Now, how do I do the same thing using FreeImage?

Comment: Since you are using MFC, why not go with [CImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwea7by5.aspx) instead? No need to pull in another dependency.

Comment: I did not know that - Is it available in VS2013?

Comment: [Yes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwea7by5(v=vs.120).aspx).

Comment: To load JPG, which CImage method do I use when I have JPG's blob data & size?

Comment: [CImage::Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwea7by5.aspx#cimage__load) has an overload to read from an [IStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380034.aspx) interface. You can construct an `IStream` on a memory buffer using [SHCreateMemStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773831.aspx). MFC may have pre-built wrapper classes as well.

Comment: I looked at SHCreateMemStream, but I do not know how my blob.data and nSize are used to create a stream?

Comment: You have a pointer and a size. `SHCreateMemStream` takes a pointer and a size.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and it worked exactly the way you described.... I used SHCreateMemStream and fed the stream to the overloaded LOAD method of CImage. Everything worked perfectly.

Thank you so much,
Makoto

```
CImage im;
IStream* is = SHCreateMemStream(Blob.pData, nSize);
HRESULT hr = im.Load(is);
RECT rect = { 0, 0, 500, 500 };
BOOL b = im.Draw(hdc, rect);
```

Comment: The answer space should just be for a solution. You can edit your answer to show what you explicitly did.

Comment: This does not answer the question (*"How to read jpg using FreeImage"*). While this is the solution *you* were looking for, it is not a solution in general. If you want to persist this answer, you should ask a new question, asking about your **real** problem (*"How to read jpg data from an MFC application"*), and answer that. Besides, the code is leaking an `IStream` object.